# How can I test for a numpy.datetime64() type/format?

Tags: types, assertion

I want to test that `exchange.context.capture_tstamp` below is a `numpy.datetime64()` type, but looking things up on other forumns, `datetime64()` is the type, but I have tried both and both don't work- any suggestions what this should be?

```
import numpy

def test_write_limit_orders(mock_write_limit_order, exchange):
    exchange.context.capture_tstamp = numpy.datetime64("2022-06-16T22:10:00.314635081")


    assert isinstance(exchange.context.capture_tstamp, numpy.datetime64())
```